# Error when trying to plot more than one graph in Gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I have a gnuplot problem, I am a beginner and I believe that they can help me ...
I am trying to reproduce the graph of this link (https://homepages.see.leeds.ac.uk/~amt6xw/Distance%20Learning/CFD5050TURB/node22.html FIGURE 4.5) and unfortunately I am not getting success. The chart plots only one of the curves (the one that is first in the code) and the last two I wrote are giving error (a lot of lines appear in the legend and there is no chart), can you help me?

And the code has also searched for reference only in the line "set trange [0:25]", which makes it impossible to plot other graphs, I need to learn how to determine several 'ranges' for variables.

```
reset

## CONFIGURAÇÕES DO ARQUIVO DE SAÍDA (http://www.gnuplotting.org/output-terminals/):

set terminal pngcairo size 800,600 enhanced font "Verdana,10"
set output "yPlus.png" 

# AJUSTE DAS MARGENS DO CONTEÚDO NO INTERIOR DA TELA:
# GUIA: l = left; r = right; t = top; b - bottom

set lmargin 7.5
set rmargin 3.5
set bmargin 3.5
set tmargin 1

set grid

# LEGENDAS LATERAIS:

set xlabel "r+" font "Verdana,10"
set ylabel "<u_{z}>+" font "Verdana,10"

# RANGE DO EIXO Y:

set parametric
set trange [0:25]

# RANGE DO EIXO X:

set logscale x 
set xrange [*:1000]
set format x "10^{%L}"

# LEGENDA DO GRÁFICO:

set key ins vert
set key top left
set key box

## CONFIGURAÇÕES DOS GRÁFICOS:

# SPALDING'S LAW OF THE WALL (https://homepages.see.leeds.ac.uk/~amt6xw/Distance%20Learning/CFD5050TURB/node22.html) (- 1/24*((k*t)**4)): 

# Karman's constant (k = 0.4):
k = 0.4187

# ...for a smooth wall (A = 0.1108):
E = 9.0

f(t) = t + 1/E*(exp(k*t) - 1 - k*t - 1/2*((k*t)**2) - 1/6*((k*t)**3))

plot f(t),t title "Spalding's Law of the Wall" with lines linetype -1

# LOGARITHIMIC OVERLAP:

g(y) = 1/k*log10(E)*y

plot for [y = 35:350] g(y),y title "Logarithimic overlap" with lines linetype -1

# LINEAR SUBLAYER:

plot for [t = 0:20] t,t title "Linear Sublayer" with lines linetype -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot everything in a single plot/graph, you need to invoke the `plot` command only once. Also, in order to use different "ranges" for different dependencies within the same plot, you could rescale the `t` variable manually as shown below. For example since `t` goes from `0` to `25`, `scale1` function transforms this to `[35; 350]` as intended...

```
set trange [0:25]

f(t) = t + 1/E*(exp(k*t) - 1 - k*t - 1/2*((k*t)**2) - 1/6*((k*t)**3))

g(y) = 1/k*log10(E)*y

scale1(t) = t*315./25 + 35
scale2(t) = t*20./25

plot \
    f(t),t title "Spalding's Law of the Wall" with lines linetype -1, \
    g(scale1(t)),scale1(t) title "Logarithimic overlap" with lines linetype -1, \
    scale2(t),scale2(t) title "Linear Sublayer" with lines linetype -1
```

Comment: Hi ewcz, Thanks for your response.

I made your recommendations, but I'm still facing a problem ... the expression g (x) is plotting the values in VERTICAL, being values in HORIZONTAL, according to the link that takes Picture 5 (shown in the first post). The equation is right and they have to produce results horizontally... link: (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2.5*log(y)+%2B+5.5,+y%3D35 .. 150).

What can I do?

Comment: *Apparently it puts the values of the range in g(x) and not in 'x' according to the equation.

Comment: Is there a way to leave the ranges independent? without depending on one in particular. This would make things much simpler and more intuitive, avoiding all this process to plot simple curves.

Comment: @MarceloJoão from the description, I think that one should just replace `g(scale1(t)),scale1(t)` with `scale1(t),g(scale1(t))`. Also, it seems to me that the equation 4.27 is rather `g(y)=1/k*log(E*y)` than `log10(E) * y`. In the latter case, the resulting values would be out of the range on the plot in Fig. 4.5